# If function doesn't have return what does it returns on if check?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
checkerFunction() {

  let checker = false;
  // Note here I only do a return if the *if* condition is fulfilled
  if (condition) {
    checker = true;
    return checker;
  }
}
```

And then I use it as a true/false check on another function:

```
anotherFunction() {
 // What will happen here if there's no return from this.checkerFunction()
 if (this.checkerFunction()) {
   somethingHappens;
 }
}
```

What will happen in

```
if (this.checkerFunction())
```

if there's no return in checkerFunction() because the condition was never true... Is it going to be interpreted as true/false or is this going to be an error and why?

Comment: function with no return will return `undefined`... that's actually the value having a variable not being initialized .. so semantically speaking it doesn't return anything

Comment: It will just return undefined which is a falsy value.
Testing this should be easy enough in the browser's console, too.

Answer (score 7):

Functions which end without hitting a `return` statement will return `undefined` (or a promise that resolves to `undefined` if they are `async`).

`undefined` is a falsy value.

This is trivial to test:

```js
function foo () {
    // Do nothing
};

const result = foo();

if (result) {
    console.log("A true value: ", result);
} else {
    console.log("A false value: ", result);
}
```